# Loops in column with multiple elements with the same value in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

As the question says. I have a column in a matrix that out of the 300000 entries the same value exists in multiple elements. For example

```
1000
1000
1000
3000
3000
6000
6000
```

I want to do a loop in which with each different value executes another function. For clarification I want my program to do something for the three rows that have the value `1000`, and then something else for the rows that have value 3000 and another thing for the rows that have value `6000`. I made a `switch` loop, but I don't believe it's logically correct. Here it is:

```
a = M(1,6)

switch a
    case M(:,6) == a 
      y=sinx;  
    case M(:,6) != a 
      b = M(:,6)
      y = 4
    case M(:,6) != b
      c = M(:,6)
      z = 5
    otherwise M(:,6) != c
      d = M(:,6)
      w = 6
end
```

Comment: If you don't think the logic of your code is correct, then it would probably be a good idea to tell us what logic you're actually trying to implement. Also, I see no loop here, or loop variable being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of mistakes:

- matlab uses `~` as `not` therefore `~=` is used to compare vectors.
- if you want to compare vectors use `isequal(a,b)` as the result from `a == b` is a vector and not a logical `true` or `false`
- `switch` already compares `M(:,6)` to `a`. What you are checking now is: `a == (M(:,6) == a)` which probably is not intended.
- It apears you want to use `M(:,6)` in the `switch` argument instead of `a`.

If you want to use a different function each time after the value of `M(:,6)` changes, you might want to try a loop like this.

```
a = M(:,6)
idx = 1;
for i = 1:numel(M(:,6))
    switch idx
        case 1
            y=sinx;
        case 2
            b = M(:,6)
            y = 4
        case 3
            c = M(:,6)
            z = 5
        otherwise
            d = M(:,6)
            w = 6

    end
    if M(i+1,6) ~= a
        a = (M(i+1,6));
        idx = idx + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on `not`. Your answer is the closest to what I am asking. What I basically ask is: in the beginning I give the value of `M(1,6)` to `a`. Then in the first case, where `M(:,6)` is equal to `a`. As long as this statement is `true`, I want to execute the first case. When the statement becomes `false`, I want the new value, let's say `b=M(1657,6)` to be the value of a new variable and then again to run the second case for as many rows as the statement is `true`. The same for the rest of the cases. `M(:,6)` is vector and cannot be used in the `switch` argument.

Comment: So M(:,6) is sorted, but you don't know which values you are going to expect and how big the groups are? Do you know how many cases there are at most?

Comment: Thank you! It works as I expected. Yes M(:,6) is sorted and I don't know how big the groups are. This time I know that the cases are four, but what happens if I don't know how many the cases are? How do we generalize this?

Comment: The standard way to generalize``switch`` is to create a default fallback behavior in ``otherwise``. You can also apply some other logic to ``idx``. For instance you could loop through your cases again.